# Masonry + Advanced Ajax Page Loader

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, jquery-masonry

I'm trying to figure out the reload code for the masonry jquery function. I have AJAX on my website and after the new content is loaded via ajax, masonry is not applied. I'm using the wordpress advanced ajax page loader plugin(http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-ajax-page-loader/). Does anyone have any insight on what I could do load masonry when the content is refreshed via ajax?

Thanks!

Comment: May you share the link of page where you want to apply this?

Comment: The website is wethebeat.com

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution:

Add the code below to the "reload code" section of the plugin settings.

```
jQuery.getScript('/wp-content/themes/simplemag/js/jquery.custom.js?ver=1.0');

jQuery(window).load();
```